# MongoDB, Sequenced Numbers and the C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Here is a link to an entry in the MongoDB documentation that describes how to do sequenced numbers: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-SequenceNumbers

My question is what is the best way to implement that solution in the C# driver.  You could do it as a two step operation where you first go to the counters collection and then updated your main collection.  I am curious how you would do it in one step like the documentation has it with the C# driver?

UPDATE:

2 Step might have been the wrong term to use.  It looks like to me they have the JavaScript function stored and then just call the JavaScript function from the insert.  That was what I meant by 1 step, how do you call the JavaScript function in the insert?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation at that link is definitely not a 1 step operation.  There is a method call in each insert statement to assign the _id field.  That is hitting the database twice for each insert.

If you wanted to make this a simpler item and you are using POCO's, you could implement a custom IIdGenerator as documented here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial.  It'll still be two steps, but it would be hidden from you (arguably not necessarily a good thing).

Comment: I have just updated the question with some more description, I think I was asking the question wrong

Comment: Yeah, you can't call a stored javascript function on insert.  The javascript function they are calling isn't stored.  It may seem that way because the sample is in javascript.  Just as an FYI: ObjectId's are strictly increasing in value over time.  What is your reason for needing an integer sequence?

Comment: No pure need for integer sequencing, I am just trying to understand the inner working of mongodb and the .net driver a little bit better.